# Very simple I/O

Tags: c, system-calls

So I am trying to do some very simple read/writes on a file. Since it's for an assignment I can't use more sophisticated functions using `File*`.

I can easily create a file and write to it but if I try to read back my content (it's the same content but my problem boils down to this) I don't get what I expect and I can't yet see why.

Here the code snippet that causes me problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
        int fdisk = open("testfile.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND);
        char buff [20] = "Just a short text!!!";
        write(fdisk, buff, sizeof(buff));
        char buff2[20];
        read((fdisk), buff2, sizeof(buff2));
        printf("Context of deleted file: %c\n",buff[1]);
        printf("Context of deleted file: %c\n",buff2[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you are getting back? My guess is that you need to rewind the file. After the write operation, it will be at the end of the file and the read is probably not returning anything meaningful.

Comment: If you use `O_CREAT` with `open()`, you need to provide a third argument, the permissions for the file that is created.  If you don't, you'll get a largely indeterminate value for the permissions.

Comment: or use different handles and close the file after the write which will cause a flush. closing seems to be missing in your code, also not a good idea.

Comment: call `lseek()` between writing and reading. Otherwise thre read/write pointer remains at EOF and you can't read anything

Comment: Also, at best you are going to get the first character from the file with the `printf` statements you are using.

Comment: I advise checking the return values from `write()` and, especially, `read()`. This will give you useful clues about where things are going wrong (and is good practice in any case!)

Comment: Since you open the file in append mode, the read position after the write is always at the end of the file, so you get no data.  You need to rethink what you want to do — rewind to the start, or seek back.  You should also check your system call return values; then you'd know that `read()` read nothing.

Comment: best to test with just a write first and see what is in the file afterwards, and then read.

Comment: Thanks everybody! As you you assumed the problem was that I didn't rewind the position. I'm aware that not closing the file isn't a good idea but as I said it's just a small extract that caused my problem. Code is now working as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a file you need to specify the file access mode:

```
int fdisk = open("testfile.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0666);
```

Otherwise the access mode is some indeterminate value.

And before reading it back you need to rewind it:

```
lseek(fdisk, 0, SEEK_SET); // rewind
```

Comment: This is actually what I needed! Thanks a bunch. As many times it's totally obvious that i have to rewind before I can actually read.. won't be forgetting this anymore I guess..
@Jonathan I know the code has more issues but it's just an extract and this was the problem it boiled down to..
Now just two more little questions.. why do I need '0666' as an argument and what does it do? And to Jonathan's proposal to use an fflush.. what would this do? I checked the man page and couldn't quite figure it out.
Thanks a bunch in advance again!

Comment: Nvm figured out the 0666 (access permissions) and why some people proposed the fflush (write back the buffer).. don't think that's actually needed here thou.

Comment: @Desperate `write` syscall does not maintain a buffer in the user-space, like `fwrite` do. Hence, no flushing is required.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `write` call leaves the file descriptor pointing to just *after* the data written (so more writes will go after that rather than overwriting the same data), so the following `read` call tries to read data after that which was written, and probably gets nothing.

Comment: Definitely gets nothing because the write was in append mode, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a combination of issues:

- You are not rewinding or re-opening the file, so when you read you are always reading from the end of the file.
- You are using append mode, so it will add data to the end of the file. This means that after the first run you will be writing data at the end of the file but always reading from the beginning (assuming you address the first problem).
- You are not setting the permissions, so you get random file permissions and the file may not be readable after creating it.
- Your print statement is only printing the second character from each buffer, rather than a full string.

Here is a minimal working example. This compiles and runs with the expected results on my machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                               
#include <fcntl.h>                                                               
#include <unistd.h>                                                              
int main(int argc, char** argv){                                                 
  int fdisk = open("testfile.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);           
  char buff[] = "Just a short text!!!";                                          
  write(fdisk, buff, sizeof(buff));                                              
  lseek(fdisk, 0, SEEK_SET);                                        
  char buff2[sizeof(buff)];                                                      
  read((fdisk), buff2, sizeof(buff2));                                           
  printf("Context of deleted file: %s\n",buff);                                  
  printf("Context of deleted file: %s\n",buff2);                                 
  return 0;
}
```

As a final note, the functions you are using (read/write) all return values indicating whether the operation was successful. You should check them. They would have indicated that the read operation in your problem was not actually reading any data (because it was at the end of the file).