# Why i cannot read from file thought it contains content?

Tags: c, io, system-calls, file-descriptor

I'm trying to create a function that duplicates a file given a file descriptor and a file name:

```
int filedup(int fd1, char *cpyfile)
{
    int fd;
    size_t  rd;
    char    buff;
    
    if (fd1 < 0 || fd1 > OPEN_MAX)
        return (-1);
    if (!validfname(fname))
        return (-1);
    fd = open(cpyfile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (fd == -1)
        return (-1);
    rd = read(fd1, &buff, 1);
    while (rd > 0)
    {
        write(fd, &buff, 1);
        rd = read(fd1, &buff, 1);
    }
    close(fd);
    return (0);
}
int main(void)
{
    int fd;

    fd = open("/tmp/cpyfromfile", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (fd == -1)
        return (-1);
    putstr_fd(strdup("hello world\n"), fd); 
    filedup(fd, "cpyfile");
    close(fd);
    return (0);
}
```

I tried to debug it, and the problem was `rd == 0` even though the file contains data.

```
$ cat ./cpyfile
$ (nothing)
```

I'm not sure what's the problem ? what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: If `cat` shows nothing, what makes you think, there is content? What is file size?

Comment: I meant ```cat copyfile``` shows no content , not ```cat copyfromfile``` , the file copied from definitely shows content as it should , when i tried to copy it's content to another the file then there's not content . read carefully ?

Comment: It looks like you open a file, write to it, then try to read from it without seeking back to the beginning.

Comment: Yeah , That's the problem either lseek or i should open it again in ```filedup```

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Write() to file descriptor disappearing when read()](//stackoverflow.com/q/53235473/90527)", "[Very simple I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29239336/90527)"

Comment: it's a custom function and it's not missing ? put str to specific fd.

Comment: putstr_fd() definition is missing in your example, you need to provide a working example for us to review